# convert an arraylist of different types

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have an arraylist that could contain 1 of 3 types (switch1, switch2, switch3).  How do I convert this to a List?

```
var switches = _switch.Switches;  
var newList = switches.Cast<SwitchObj>().ToList();
```

This didn't work.  Here is what is in each of switch1, switch2, switch3

```
string DeviceType 
string Name
string[] State
```

Comment: what language you have to use

Comment: @all I guess I didn't explain this well enough.   I have objects in the arraylist.  Each object has string, string, and sting[].  The object types can be different depending on what was added.  So I could have an arraylist of 2 Switch1 objects, or it could be 3 of switch2 objects.  I need to convert this to a List<t> of a single type called SwitchObj.  I can't change how the arraylist was created.  Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArrayList type is a vestigial artifact of the days before generics.  You don't need to use it anymore and (if you really wanted to) you could just create a `List<object>`.  Of course, that won't solve your problem because you are trying to cast two disparate types (`string` and `string[]`) to the same type, which doesn't make much sense.

My advice would be to simply store only one type of object in the collection.  It looks like your types would all fit well as properties of a single class, so...

```
class Device
{
    public Device( string name, string type, string[] state = null )
    {
        Name = name;
        DeviceType = type;
        State = state;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string DeviceType { get; }
    public string[] State { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need only populate your collection with `Device` objects and all of your casting issues disappear.

```
List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
devices.Add( new Device( "Device1", "SomeType" ) );
devices.Add( new Device( "Device2", "SomeType" ) );
devices.Add( new Device( "Device3", "SomeType" ) );

foreach( Device d in devices )
{
    // do stuff with d.Name, d.State, and d.DeviceType
}
```

EDIT to address updated question:

Either the two types are compatible or they are not, there's no getting around that.  Since they are not, can you modify the classes to implement a single interface?  For example, if both classes implemented the following interface you could simply maintain a `List<IDevice>` collection and treat them generically.  So, the code becomes something like...

```
interface IDevice
{
    string Name { get; }
    string DeviceType { get; }
    string[] State { get; set; }
}

class DeviceTypeOne : IDevice
{
    // constructor omitted

    public string Name { get; }
    public string DeviceType { get; }
    public string[] State { get; set; }
}

class DeviceTypeTwo : IDevice
{
    // constructor omitted

    public string Name { get; }
    public string DeviceType { get; }
    public string[] State { get; set; }
}

List<IDevice> devices = new List<IDevice>();
devices.Add( new DeviceTypeOne( "Device1", "SomeType" ) );
devices.Add( new DeviceTypeTwo( "Device2", "SomeType" ) );

foreach( IDevice d in devices )
{
    // do stuff with d.Name, d.State, and d.DeviceType
    // you now just deal with each object through the IDevice interface
}
```

If you can't modify the code then you will simply have to deal with them separately based on their type.  For example:

```
IEnumerable<SomeDeviceType> lsOne = arrayList.OfType<SomeDeviceType>();
IEnumerable<SomeOtherDeviceType> lsTwo = arrayList.OfType<SomeOtherDeviceType>();
```

Comment: @rob morgan: Updated my response.

Comment: I don't have differnet types in the arraylist, they are all of the same type.  Sometimes they are all switch1 and other times they are all switch2.

Comment: @rob morgan:  Then I don't understand the problem.  If they are all the same type then you already know which way to cast.  If you are stuck not knowing ahead of time for whatever reason just test the first element: `if( array.FirstOrDefault() is Sometype ) ... else ...`

Comment: we're getting closer :)  I'm concerned that the arraylist could, at sometime contain Switch4.  I would have to mod my code again using If else statements.  any other idea?

Comment: @rob morgan: Ok, so, this is either a really bad architecture that you are stuck with or one that you can change.  Let's figure out which it is first.  Do you have the source code for the `switchX` types?

Comment: I don't have the source and I'm using a reference to the library

Comment: Well, if there's no base class and you are only given an ArrayList then you are pretty much stuck with checking the type of each element.

Comment: how do I do that so that I can convert it?

Comment: You can use the `is` keyword to test the type of an object and/or (for reference types) you can use a safe cast.  A safe cast in the form of `obj as Type` will return null if the cast failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast if all three types have the same base type. If your types are string,string and string[] there is no way other than cast to List.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this must be complicated.  My types in the arraylist consist of Switch1(string,string and string[]) and I need to convert it to a List,  Or the arraylist could consist of Switch2(string,string and string[]).  no matter what types are in the arraylist I need to convert them to SwitchObj(string,string and string[]).

Comment: @rob morgan: I added another update in response to this comment.

Comment: @rob morgan: Ok, I take that back; this is just nasty.  Are you sure that `switch1`, `switch2`, and `switch3` don't all inherit from the same base type?  Seems like a rather poor design IMO.

Comment: I'm dealing with the hand I'm delt.  don't all inherit from the same base type? Nope

Comment: If they don't inherit from the same base type and you can't add one you may want to define a common type and map all three switch types onto this common type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Cast`, you could use `OfType`, which will return a sequence of items that match the type specified. It's equivalent to `Cast` but doesn't throw if an item doesn't conform.

In your case, `switches.OfType<SwitchObj>().ToList()` would be a `List<SwitchObj>`. Any other items in the `ArrayList` will be ignored.